# jquery confirm box when user hit the close button in web browser's window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to implement the same functionality as Javascript window.confirm() Box with jquery Modal Dialog Box when user hits the Web Browser's close button or leave the page or reload the page.

```
//////javascript code//////


sessionStorage["isTrue"] = false;
$(".PassReqNotes,.datePassed1").change(function () {
    sessionStorage["isTrue"]= true;
});
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sessionValue = sessionStorage["isTrue"].toLocaleString();
    if (sessionValue == "true") {
        isTrue = false;
        sessionStorage["isTrue"] = null;
        //return 'If you leave page, You may lose some changes';
       return window.confirm = dialog();
    }
});



function dialog(event) {
    $("#dialog-confirmPassReq").removeClass('hide').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "<div class='widget-header'><h4 class='smaller'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle red'></i> Delete Photo?</h4></div>",
        title_html: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                html: "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-110'></i>&nbsp; ok",
                "class": "btn btn-danger btn-xs btnDeleteActivityPhoto",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                }
            },
            {
                html: "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-times bigger-110'></i>&nbsp; Cancel",
                "class": "btn btn-xs",
                "id": "btnClosePassReq",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: yes you can do that with the combination of `window.onbeforeunload` and `event.preventDefault `

Comment: yes i tried with window.onbeforeunload and event.preventDefault ,but it did not works, when user request other page,it do not ask confirmation and redirects on new page

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //your code
};
```

Comment: yes i tried with window.onbeforeunload and it shows the Jquery confirm Box but do not wait to ask the confirmation of user and reloads the page .